# Issue with getting an element with dynamic ID with the function getElementsByTagName - NightwatchJS

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, nightwatch.js, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to make an automated test using `NoghtwatchJS`.

I am dealing with a UI that contains elements with dynamic IDs. I have to click on a particular element. I am thinking about using `gelElementByTagName('aria-label')` in mycase. This is the code I used :

```
var labels,i
labels = getElementsByTagName('aria-label');
    for ( i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        if (labels[i].htmlFor == 'Next') {
            var elem = getElementById(labels[i].htmlFor)
        };
    };
```

I have the issue element not defined :

> ReferenceError: getElementsByTagName is not defined

Do you have any idea how I could solve this problem?

I have tried :

```
getElementsByTagName('aria-label')
element.getElementsByTagName('aria-label')
document.getElementsByTagName('aria-label')
```

Comment: Do you *really* have `<aria-label>` elements? Or another element, such as a `<div>`, `<span>`, `<label>`... with `aria-label` as an attribute-value? Can you show a snippet of the representative HTML that you're trying to find?

Comment: Hello David, thank you for your reply.
find below a snippet of the code I am trying to work on : 

 <button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next slick-arrow" aria-label="Next" role="button" style="display: block;" aria-disabled="false">Next</button>

Comment: Hello again David, I followed your thinking and I found that I don't need the getElementByTagName, to do this, I searched the element with its classname and I am trying to get from there to what I want, till now I am using this code :  labels =  document.getElementsByClassName('slick-next slick-arrow') console.log(labels.item(3).getAttribute('aria-label'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to make this work in Nightwatch is to use the [execute](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/execute.html) comand

Your code should looke something like this:

```
browser.execute(function() {
            return document.getElementsByTagName('aria-label').length;

        }, function(result) {
            for (let i = 0; i < result.value; i++) {
                if (labels[i].htmlFor == 'Next') {
                   let elem = getElementById(labels[i].htmlFor)
      };
  });
```

Comment: Hello Lucas your answer led me to the right code. Actually, I used this function to be able to execute the methods on the browser itself. Whereas, getElementsByTagName is not the function I needed as I followed David thinking above. I used the classname to access the element. I am still working on the thing since it was not very clear to me how to handle attributes. Thank you very much for your help. It made it easier for me